# How to solve Error while proxying to API in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

i have setup the following proxies:

```
const app = require('express')();
const  proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');


app.use('/api', proxy({ target: 'https://swapi-graphql.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/index', changeOrigin: true})); 
app.use('/image', proxy({ target: 'localhost:8000' , changeOrigin: true})); 


app.listen(8080);
```

The /api route proxies normally but the /image proxy returns the following error :

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /image from localhost:8080 to localhost:8000 (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

The issue is not in my image api because when i post directly to the /image route, the issue doesnt happen. Only when i do it via port 8080.

What I tried:

Changing the port -> didnt work

Comment: maybe you need to specify the protocol as well, like http: //localhost:8000

Comment: @SándorBakos hero , it works!!

Comment: I am happy that I could help